# Why is it not allowing me to input just 5 numbers, when I run it, it allows me to input 6

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11d
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double [] anArray;  // declares an array of integers
        anArray = new double [5];        
        int min=0;       

        //Initalizes the array values//
        System.out.println ("Enter 5 numbers of your choosing"); 

        double a = in.nextDouble();       
        for ( int count=0; count < 5; count++)
        {
            anArray[count] = a;
            a = in.nextDouble();
        }

        //Prints array values//
        for (double value : anArray)
            System.out.println ("Element at index " + (min++) + ":"+ value + "" ); 
    }
}
```

It runs, but I only want to input 5 numbers, not sure what I am doing wrong. It allows me to enter six with like a limit of 5, curious how to change it please

Answer (score 1):

Because you get one `double` **before** your loop. Change it to something like

```
// double a = in.nextDouble();       
for (int count=0; count < 5; count++)
{
    double a = in.nextDouble();
    anArray[count] = a;
}
```

**or** eliminate `a` altogether like

```
for (int count=0; count < 5; count++)
{
    anArray[count] = in.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting a double first time and then iterating through a loop which accepts 5 doubles i.e. in total you are accepting 6 doubles.

You have to edit your for loop as,

```
    for ( int count=0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        anArray[count] = in.nextDouble();
    }
```